# Bloomberg C# / CS.NET SDK for STDY Functions

Tags: programming, bloomberg

I have downloaded and installed the CS.NET SDK from STDY. I have installed this as admin and had no problems with the install. However, when I open VS2017 (last version supported by BBG) I do not see the option to create a new project that is a Bloomberg Custom Study, nor do I see the Study toolbar in VS (for screenshots of of both of these see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878202/Development-of-Custom-Studies-for-Bloomberg-Termin).

Any ideas? Response from the BBG Helpdesk was 'we don't support this'.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the package in your project?

Comment: Yes. As I should be seeing the option to create a Bloomberg Custom Study before I even open a project, that is not the issue.